# Error on Parsing the empty string for an Enum : JSON parse error: Cannot coerce empty String (\"\")

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson

I've been trying to solve this error which happens upon parsing an empty string for my enum values.I have tried the following solutions

```
getJacksonObjectMapper(template).coercionConfigFor(LogicalType.Enum).setCoercion(CoercionInputShape.EmptyString,CoercionAction.AsNull)
```

and

```
getJacksonObjectMapper(template).deserializationConfig.with(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
  
getJacksonObjectMapper(template).enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
```

can someone help me out with this problem ? The error trace looks like this

```
JSON parse error: Cannot coerce empty String (\"\") to `Gender` value (but could if coercion was enabled using `CoercionConfig`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot coerce empty String (\"\") to `Gender` value (but could if coercion was enabled using `CoercionConfig`)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream);
```

and my enum is

```
enum Gender{
M, F;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).